# How to use replace() to remove comma and strings before it with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

First of all I have searched the answer for my query and couldn't find any which using replace() function.

In the following string, **Strada Genova 204, 10024 Moncalieri** I need to replace comma and the string before it with null, so, the outpt will be just **10024 Moncalieri**

I tried  `$('.class-name').replace(/[^\,]*,(.*)/, "")` and didnt work. Changed the regex part several times and nothing worked.

Comment: Maybe `.replace(/[^,]*,/, "")` will do? Why capture the rest with `(.*)`?

Comment: I tried that too, it didnt work either.

Comment: JQuery does not feature regex, the RegExp class is a JavaScript thing. You may run a regex replacement on strings. You need something like `$('.class-name').text().replace(/.*,/, "")`

Comment: But, there are lots of similar strings, cant do the string replacement for each and every string.

Comment: .replace(/[^,]+,(.*)/g,'$1')

Comment: Should you be using only the `.replace()` method? Because there's another way to achieve it without using that method.

Comment: ok, can you please share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to append new filtered text into the HTML element with a class name `filtered`

Note: **Be sure to load jQuery from either locally or CDN**.

HTML

```
<p class="class-name">Strada Genova 204, 10024 Moncalieri</p>
<p class="filtered"></p>
```

Javascript

```
$('.filtered').append($('.class-name').text().replace(/[\w\s]*,?\s?/, ""));
```

JS Fiddle => https://jsfiddle.net/sam1205/gqspwd0a/136/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `split(',')` and get the last element in the array.

Like this:

[Code pen example](https://codepen.io/dennise89/pen/JxZyRZ)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var str="Strada Genova 204, 10024 Moncalieri";
console.log(str.replace(/[^,]+,(\s+)?(.*)/g,"$2"));
```

`[^,]+` Every thing not including `,` then `,` then `(\s+)?` if any withespaces and finally captured part `(.*)`